# Issues installing symfony on a Hostgator apache server

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

So, i am trying to install symfony on a subdomain, my layout is like this:

```
Root
  public_html/symfony
```

(The subdomain is named symfony and its webroot is public_html/symfony)

I am installing symfony via composer, and i install it at

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /home1/user/public_html/symfony
```

When i try to access:

```
http://symfony.domain.com/web/config.php
```

I get: This script is only accessible from localhost.

When i try to access:

```
http://symfony.domain.com/config.php
```

I get hostgator 404 not found

What am i doing incorectly?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `config.php` It is located under `Symfony/web/config.php`

Line 7 to 13:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

One option is to comment out this whole part or add your own IP to the given array.

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
    'YOUR_OWN_IP_HERE',
)))
...
```

It has to do with security concerns so that nobody can access the config.php unless he is authorized to access it. 
Without that basically everybody which has the link or finds it could access this file.

If you just comment out this in the `config.php` please remind to undo this when you go live/prod environment.
Otherwise everybody could change your Symfony configuration.